# Is it possible to compare session with sql?

Tags: php, sql, session, if-statement

I'm trying to use if statement by comparing $resultsub (pass by sql) and $_id (session). I have tried to use <> and == . It seem doesn't work. I think it have some error on my **if statement**. Please help me to correct my php code.

This is the code.

```
    <?php
include 'db_connect.php';

session_start(); 
$_id = $_SESSION['staff_id'];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $sub_code = $_POST['sub_code'];
    $doc_name = $_POST['doc_name'];

    $checksub = "SELECT staff_id FROM subject WHERE sub_code='$sub_code' ";
    $resultsub = mysqli_query( $link,$checksub) or die("Query failed");

    if ($resultsub == $_id)
    {


      if((IsChecked('tick','delete')) && (IsChecked('tick','add')))
      {
           //some other code 

      }
    }

   else
     echo "you cannot upload file. Only coordinator for every subject only can upload file." ;


}


?>
```

It does not show any error. But it does not check my if statement and jump to else.

Comment: can you do `var_dump($resultsub);` and update the question with the results?

Comment: `$resultsub` is a resource. You should `fetch`.

Comment: your variable `resultsub` has query resource hence it does not match with id. use `mysqli_fetch_array` to get your data from database and then compare staff_id with your id

Comment: What is `$link`? Also, even if you're only returning a single row, you still need to 'fetch' from the `$resultsub` resource (you are returned a resource, not a string). A final note - this is a perfect example of SQL injection, you should look it up as this code is v. insecure.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you show me where should I fetch? I'm still new on php. I have do as what you said and it does not work for me. Thankyou for helping. @DanWalker

Comment: Take a look at the answer someone posted. The `mysqli_query()` function returns a `Resource`, NOT a `string`. A string is just text, like you're comparing to above, but a `Resource` is a special object, you must first 'extract' the data from the resource using `mysqli_fetch()`

Comment: Thank you for helping! It work like a charm! :) @DanWalker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try starting your session just after the php open tag like following

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_connect.php';
```

and the second thing is that you need to fetch the required field from your variable `$result_sub` by using the function `mysqli_fetch_array()` try this code.

```
    <?php
session_start(); 
include 'db_connect.php';


$_id = $_SESSION['staff_id'];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $sub_code = $_POST['sub_code'];
    $doc_name = $_POST['doc_name'];

    $checksub = "SELECT staff_id FROM subject WHERE sub_code='$sub_code' ";
    $resultsub = mysqli_query( $link,$checksub) or die("Query failed");

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultsub,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if ($row['nameOfYourIdField'] == $_id)
    {


      if((IsChecked('tick','delete')) && (IsChecked('tick','add')))
      {
           //some other code 

      }
    }

   else
     echo "you cannot upload file. Only coordinator for every subject only can upload file." ;


}


?>
```

Comment: Though the answer is correct, OP should be warned about the danger of a sql injection.